# Possible NGINX issue with PHPMyAdmin

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin, nginx-config

pulling my hair out with this one!
I can't figure out why PHPMyAdmin is logging in ok and showing menu's, but there is no database information displayed. The left hand database tree is gone and the main window where you would manage a database is also blank (just empty space).
The menus are loading ok so I suspect a frame related issue as when I look at page source, there is just no HTML there.

I have Certbot install a letsencrypt certificate and NGINX 1.20.2. PHP is 8.1.3 and Ubuntu 20. I have tried multiple fresh installs of PHPMyAdmin.

Here are my NGINX configs in case I am missing something there:

sites-enabled/default

```
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
    
        root /var/www/html;
    
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
    
        server_name _;
    
        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
    
        add_header X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM http://site.uk";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM http://www.site.uk";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM https://site.uk";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM https://www.site.uk";
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1";
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    
    }
    
    server {
        root /var/www/html;
    
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
    server_name _; # managed by Certbot
    
    
        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
    
        location ~ .php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        }
    
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/fx5.uk/fullchain.pem; # managed by C>
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/fx5.uk/privkey.pem; # managed by>
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    
    }
    
    server {
    
    #changed
    if ($host = site.uk) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    
    
        listen 80 ;
        listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name _;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
    
    }
```

nginx.conf

```
    user www-data;
    worker_processes auto;
    pid /run/nginx.pid;
    include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;
    
    events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
    }
    
    http {
    
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        server_tokens off;
    
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;
    
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    
        gzip on;
    
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    }
```

Comment: Are there any hints in the nginx error log? I recently saw another post about a similar problem where there was a problem with the ssl handshake, but I don't know enough about Let's Encrypt to figure that out. Can you try setting up a HTTP site for phpMyAdmin so you're bypassing Let's Encrypt and all of the encryption and see if that works?

Comment: I have tried using a different domain and taking https out of the equation by making a new virtual host for the domain and the problem persists.